# Django ArrayField null=True migration with Postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql

So in Django docs for creating new fields on Postgresql it says ([Full description](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#postgresql)):

> ... it’s recommended you always create new columns with `null=True`, as this way they will be added immediately.

What if I want to create an ArrayField, something like this:

```
tags = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default=''), default=list, null=True)
```

Should I also pass `null=True` into `CharField` which is inside this `ArrayField`?

Comment: From reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield it would seem to me you just need to make the actual `ArrayField` nullable, as the *base_field* is just used for type, validation etc.

Comment: Note that if you set `null=True`, you'll probably want to set `blank=True` as well. Otherwise you will get errors when cleaning model forms.

Comment: @IljaEverilä link is broke

Comment: @java-addict301 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do not think setting `null=True` on the inner type gives you any benefit. The note in the docs you refer to only applies to the column itself, so as long as the `ArrayField` is nullable, the database will not have to perform a full table rewrite.

If you allow the inner type to be null, you'll have to deal with that in your code, which might not be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If u are adding the null=True only because documentation says:

> ... it’s recommended you always create new columns with `null=True`, as this way they will be added immediately.

I don't think that would be necessary here in the `ArrayField`. Because you have already added a default value to your field. So any entry which is already present in database will have this default value(which is empty list in this case).

`null=True` is added so that, in case you don't specify a default value, the field value can be set to null, and you don't have enter a default value manually during migration.

In future if u don't plan to enter null values to this field, then you can omit the `null=True` part.

Let us say you have a table with following data:

```
 id | user_id 
----+---------
  1 | 66
  2 | 105
  3 | 110
  4 | 174
```

After adding `default=list` and doing migrations, your data would be something like this. Note that you don't need to specify `null=True` in this case.

```
 id | user_id | tag 
----+---------+-----
  1 | 66      | {}
  2 | 105     | {}
  3 | 110     | {}
  4 | 174     | {}
```

In case, you don't specify a default value and set `null=True`, you data would be:

```
 id | user_id | tag 
----+---------+-----
  1 | 66      | 
  2 | 105     | 
  3 | 110     | 
  4 | 174     |
```